# Why is this MySQL join query producing wrong result?

Tags: mysql

Here is a MySQL query joining 3 tables, but only the result of the jobtitle table is printed correctly why the other two are wrong duplicated results.

```
SELECT `booking`.`receipt_no`, `client`, `operator`, `discount`, `total_amount`, `amount_paid`, `balance`, `date`, `jobtitle`, `quantity`, `amount`, `date_paid`, `old_balance`, `debtor_amount_paid`, `new_balance`
FROM (`booking`)
JOIN `jobtitle` ON `jobtitle`.`bookingID` = `booking`.`bookingID`
JOIN `first_graphics_debtors` ON `first_graphics_debtors`.`receipt_no` = `booking`.`receipt_no`
WHERE `booking`.`receipt_no` =  '753263343'
AND `first_graphics_debtors`.`receipt_no` =  '753263343'
GROUP BY `jobtitle`.`quantity`
```

How can I fix this?

**The schema for the three tables.**

Booking

```
CREATE TABLE `booking` (
`bookingID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`receipt_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`client` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`operator` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`discount` int(11) NOT NULL,
`total_amount` int(64) NOT NULL,
`amount_paid` int(32) NOT NULL,
`balance` int(32) NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`bookingID`)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=209 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Jobtitle

```
CREATE TABLE `jobtitle` (
`jobtitleID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`jobtitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
`amount` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`jobtypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`bookingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`jobtitleID`)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=463 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

First_graphics_debtors

```
CREATE TABLE `first_graphics_debtors`
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`receipt_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date_paid` date NOT NULL,
`old_balance` int(32) NOT NULL,
`debtor_amount_paid` int(32) NOT NULL,
`new_balance` int(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**After inserting few data**

Booking

```
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------+------------+
    | bookingID | receipt_no | client   | operator | discount | total_amount | amount_paid | balance | date       |
    +-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------+------------+
    |       205 |  156872940 | Osaro    | Obi      |       10 |       156380 |      135000 |    5742 | 2012-05-15 |
    |       206 |  227349168 | Amaka    | Stephen  |        4 |        73250 |       70320 |       0 | 2012-05-15 |
    |       207 |  155732278 | Aghahowa | Ibori    |        0 |       116836 |       15000 |  101836 | 2012-05-15 |
    |       208 |  753263343 | Chaka    | Stephen  |       10 |       231290 |       56000 |  152161 | 2012-05-15 |
    +-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------+------------+
```

Jobtitle

```
+------------+---------------------------+----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| jobtitleID | jobtitle                  | quantity | amount | jobtypeID | bookingID |
+------------+---------------------------+----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|        454 | A1 Full Colour            |       10 | 4334   |         1 |       205 |
|        455 | Complementry Card         |       20 | 5652   |         2 |       205 |
|        456 | A4 Printout (graphics)B/W |       25 | 2930   |         4 |       206 |
|        457 | Scan                      |        2 | 4334   |         5 |       207 |
|        458 | A4 Full Colour            |      199 | 500    |         3 |       207 |
|        459 | ID Card                   |        2 | 4334   |         2 |       207 |
|        460 | A3 Full Colour            |       10 | 4334   |         3 |       208 |
|        461 | Flex Banner               |       20 | 2930   |         2 |       208 |
|        462 | A2 Single Colour          |      199 | 650    |         1 |       208 |
+------------+---------------------------+----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

First_graphics_debtors

```
+----+------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+
| id | receipt_no | date_paid  | old_balance | debtor_amount_paid | new_balance |
+----+------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+
|  7 |  156872940 | 2012-05-15 |        5742 |               5000 |         742 |
|  8 |  156872940 | 2012-05-15 |        5742 |               5742 |           0 |
|  9 |  753263343 | 2012-05-15 |      152161 |             152161 |           0 |
| 13 |  753263343 | 2012-05-15 |      152161 |              14524 |      137637 |
| 14 |  753263343 | 2012-05-15 |      152161 |               2000 |      150161 |
| 15 |  753263343 | 2012-05-15 |      152161 |               1000 |      151161 |
+----+------------+------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

**When I run the above query I get this output:**

```
+------------+--------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------+------------+------------------+----------+--------+------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+
| receipt_no | client | operator | discount | total_amount | amount_paid | balance | date       | jobtitle         | quantity | amount | date_paid  | old_balance | debtor_amount_paid | new_balance |
+------------+--------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------+------------+------------------+----------+--------+------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+
|  753263343 | Chaka  | Stephen  |       10 |       231290 |       56000 |  152161 | 2012-05-15 | A3 Full Colour   |       10 | 4334   | 2012-05-15 |      152161 |             152161 |           0 |
|  753263343 | Chaka  | Stephen  |       10 |       231290 |       56000 |  152161 | 2012-05-15 | Flex Banner      |       20 | 2930   | 2012-05-15 |      152161 |             152161 |           0 |
|  753263343 | Chaka  | Stephen  |       10 |       231290 |       56000 |  152161 | 2012-05-15 | A2 Single Colour |      199 | 650    | 2012-05-15 |      152161 |             152161 |           0 |
+------------+--------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------+------------+------------------+----------+--------+------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

Data on the columns below are repeated three times, instead of getting data from the four rows relating to the receipt_no

```
    date_paid, old_balance, debtor_amount_paid, new_balance
```

Comment: What's wrong about the results now?

Comment: My guess is that there is a misunderstanding of GROUP BY happening.  Note that you're grouping by a field in jobtitle and that's also the only field you think is correct.

Comment: As a note; the WHERE clause is implicit in the JOIN - you don't need to specify the match for the fields on both sides of the JOIN;
---> WHERE `booking`.`receipt_no` =  '753263343'
would be sufficient.

Comment: You shouldn't `GROUP BY a` and then have `SELECT b` without an aggregate function. In most databases this would be a serious error which would prevent the query from even executing. MySQL is more lenient, but you should only do it if you really understand when it makes sense to do so. You can also configure MySQL to disallow this type of query to reduce the chance of making errors. "To disable the MySQL GROUP BY extension, enable the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: I don't have privilege to attach images, how can show my table structure?

Comment: @sality: `SHOW CREATE TABLE booking` etc...

Comment: kindly explain what results you were expecting so we could give you the correct answers, your displaying the queries up there but it does not clearly explain what results you really want to attain cause it may depend on the relationship of each table some may have duplicate results that would be natural in some instances depending on the relationship defined in your database.

Comment: I have edited the question as clear as i can. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, remove the GROUP BY clause. If you are wanting to to eliminate duplicate rows from being returned using the GROUP BY, then include all of the expressions in the SELECT list in the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT `booking`.`receipt_no`, `client`, `operator`, `discount`, `total_amount`, `amount_paid`, `balance`, `date`, `jobtitle`, `quantity`, `amount`, `date_paid`, `old_balance`, `debtor_amount_paid`, `new_balance`
FROM (`booking`)
JOIN `jobtitle` ON `jobtitle`.`bookingID` = `booking`.`bookingID`
JOIN `first_graphics_debtors` ON `first_graphics_debtors`.`receipt_no` = `booking`.`receipt_no`
WHERE `booking`.`receipt_no` =  '753263343'
AND `first_graphics_debtors`.`receipt_no` =  '753263343'
GROUP BY `booking`.`receipt_no`, `client`, `operator`, `discount`, `total_amount`, `amount_paid`, `balance`, `date`, `jobtitle`, `quantity`, `amount`, `date_paid`, `old_balance`, `debtor_amount_paid`, `new_balance`
```

MySQL has a feature that lets you omit non-aggregates from the GROUP BY clause. To disable this feature, and make MySQL work like other relational databases:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

---

[ADDENDUM]

You ask "How can I fix this", but we aren't give a clear indication of the result set you expect to have returned.

We fully expect some "duplicates" to be returned when you have a one-to-many relationship between the joined tables.

For example, suppose I have an `order` table and a `line_item` table, and an order can have zero, one or more associated rows in `line_item`, but a `line_item` is associated with one `order`. When I run a query like:

```
SELECT o.id, l.id
  FROM orders o
  JOIN line_item l ON l.order_id = o.id
```

I expect to have "duplicate" values of o.id returned for every order that has more than one line_item associated with it.

I strongly suspect the issue is with the use of "receipt_no" as the join predicate. Normally, join predicates are of the form  `child_table.parent_key = parent_table.key`

I recommend you run a query that pulls the primary key values from each table

```
SELECT b.bookingID
     , j.ID
     , d.ID
  FROM booking b
  JOIN jobtitle j ON j.bookingID = b.bookingID
  JOIN first_graphics_debtors d ON d.receipt_no = b.receipt_no
 WHERE b.receipt_no = '753263343'
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

That will show you where you are getting the "duplicates". Without a schema definition, and some sample data, that's about all I can tell you.

Comment: If that's what he wants, it would be simpler to use DISTINCT. But having duplicate rows in your result set is usually a sign that you are doing something wrong (or that your original data contains duplicate rows).

Comment: Everything is now duplicated just like what i have before using GROUP BY.

Comment: @MarkByers. When joined two tables booking and jobtitle, everything was ok, but immediately i added the first_graphics_debtors table, then came duplicates. What could be wrong with the third join?

Comment: @sality: you are getting duplicates because there are multiple rows in the `first_graphics_debtors` table that match (i.e. satisfy the specified join criteria, in this case `receipt_no = '753263343'`)

Comment: thanks spencer7593 i will try to provide those, but i hope you will still be available then. I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @sality: use the SHOW CREATE TABLE statement to get the table definitions

Comment: sorry, i don't know how to use this